# Overview of Android development with C++

Tags: java, android, c++, difference, flowchart

I'm looking for a little bit of a compare/contrast on the differences between developing for Android with C++ vs. straight Java. For example, what extra steps should I expect to go through to interface C++ code with the Android system? I know that C++ can get me closer to the hardware and (sometimes) give me better performance, depending on the app. But in practice, how would a flowchart of developing with Java compare to a flowchart of developing with C++?

THANKS!

Comment: It's pretty mad to develop the full app using NDK(c/c++), you may use it when there is a real need that you can't do it with the normal SDK like performance in image processing and game development...

Comment: errr - well this isn't something you get too often. If I am correct - A LOT, like everything. Android is developed in Java and maintains being a Java based discipline. Every step Google has taken and will take surrounding Android considers Java. My 2cents, its already challenging enough to orchestrate all of the elements which underly Android development - now take each one of those challenges and amplify it by the cost in time and energy for the extra effort you are putting in. PS: your signing up to be the wolf who leaves the wolfpack.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can make an app fully made out of C++ or C. NDK is only used if you want to implement little of C in your Java Android APP, don't expect a lot from it. Most app use straight Java and XML (Maybe SQL) for developing android apps. Don't rely on it, since apps run faster on android when developed with Java than C language. About your flowchart question, Idk what you mean by that. If you mean visio flowchart then it would be the same, because C and Java has similar wording when it comes into programming, like declaring variables, and data types..etc. Summery don't expect a lot or much. Goodluck!